# How to pythonically order triplets of line into columns and avoiding doing that for doublets of line?

Tags: python, file, text, rows

Sorry if my question is not so clear. Basically what I am trying to do is to identify by reading the file 3 non empty lines in a row (triplet) and for each triplet, sort them into another file in columns (as explained below). One tricky part is to do this only for triplets and not doublets (two non empty lines in a row).

Input:

```
line1
line2
line3
(empty line)
(empty line)
line4
line5
(empty line)
line6
line7
line8
(empty line)
(empty line)
line9
line10
(empty line)
line11
line12
line13
```

```
output: 
line1 line2 line3 
line6 line7 line8 
line11 line12 line13
```

You can notice that doublets can follow or be followed by two empty lines.
I would appreciate any kind of help with my current problem as I am a python debutant and I am stuck with my code after hours attempting something. Thank you:)

Comment: It would help if you can share some code. For example, how are you reading the data and what have you tried.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read the following documentation, then edit, and rephrase the question. [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), & [On Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Always provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with code, data, errors, current & expected output, as [formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to count the number of non-empty lines you have read so far.
If you encounter an empty line and you know you have only read two non-empty lines since the last empty line, you can throw the last lines away.
However, if you find that you have read three non-empty lines, you write them to the new file.

```py
with open('input_file.txt', 'r') as input_file:
    with open('output_file.txt', 'w') as output_file:
        non_empty = 0
        previous_lines = []
        for line in input_file.readlines():
            if line == '\n':
                if non_empty == 3:  # found a triple
                    output_file.write(' '.join(previous_lines) + '\n')
                # if it's not a triple, just ignore it
                # reset the counter so we can detect the next triple
                non_empty = 0
                previous_lines = []
            else:
                # record a non-empty line for later use
                previous_lines.append(line.replace('\n', ''))
                # and important: count how many non-empty lines there are
                non_empty += 1
```

Comment: Hello cherrywoods, thank you for the useful comment. The strategy you propose seems very well adapted here. Surprinsingly, as I try this code it does not wright anything in the output file. I understand the whole nice strategy but one point is unclear to me: why use ' ' on line 8 after the first parenthesis please ? thank you

Comment: And why use the .replace('\n', '')), what is the purpose of this ? Is it to re-empty the previous_line so you can add another triplet later ? thank you.

Comment: Hey there,  the `' '` on line 8 (before join) inserts a space between the strings that were found in the previous lines. I tried the code one more and it worked fine for me. The desired content is in the output file. Did you make sure to close/flush the output file (in case your are not using "with").

Comment: Using .replace('\n', '') to remove the newline character at the end of each line in the input file. Just try what happens if you omit it... If writing to a file still does not work, replace `output_file.write` with `print` to investigate the output.

Comment: Thank you. My file has 60000 lines, hopefully the archetype I described previously represents correctly my file. One difference with the original file is that what I call a line here actually ressembles this format : 91 W B  126.23    8.79 (with potential space at the very beginning of the line)

Comment: That shouldn't make a difference with my code. Replace `' '` on line 8 with a different separator if you want the elements of your tripled e.g. separated by commas (in that case use `', '` or `','`).

Comment: Made it work, thank s a lot for the precious help. Have a good day cherrywoods.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe consider accepting my answer if it helped you so future visitors know that the answer helped solving the problem :)

Comment: I am quite new here sorry, I've just validated it, thanks for the tip.